# How do you say "nice to meet you" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, saludos, conversación

Say you are in Spain and you get introduced to someone in a, let's say, formal context: how do you say *"nice to meet you"*?

Also, is there any difference in Latin America? And what if you are in an informal context?

My guess is that something like the following is fine:

> Encantado de conocerte / conocerle

But it may be interesting to see other options

Comment: I was checking and this hadn't been asked yet!

Comment: Try this link : http://www.howdoyousay.net/english-spanish/Nice_to_meet_you/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you indicate in the question

> Encantado de conocerte / conocerle

may be the best option. If it is a formal context I would favor the "usted" form.

Other forms would be

> Mucho gusto en conocerle / Encantado de conocerle

which is sometimes shortened as

> Mucho gusto

or

> Encantado

Which makes also valid

> (Es) Un placer  <sub>(Es un placer conocerle)</sub>

Comment: In Latin America we say "Mucho gusto" or "Encantado". Mostly all the time. While we shake hands and we make eye contact. Specially in business!

Comment: Is also good to add that conoceTe is more familiar or informal while conocerLe is more formal and denotes more respect towards the person being met.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar está simple oración:

> *Un gusto en conocerte*

o

> *Un gusto...*

Pero dependiendo de la confianza:

> *Me gustó conocerte, la verdad que la pasé muy bien con vos...*

Comment: Nice!  Note the last one is to be used after meeting the person, maybe at the end of the encounter. I was asking for the first thing to say, like when shaking hands.

Comment: Justamente, ***"gusto en conocerte"***, no esta gramaticalmente correcto, pero en el habla se dice así. por eso lo puse así no es que me halla equivocado en mi ortografía.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer could be: "Gusto en conocerte".

Comment: También se puede decir, más sencillamente e informalmente, cuando te presentan a alguien. "Hola, X, ¿ qué tal  ?"

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you = Encantada de conocerte/Mucho gusto/Encantado

It’s nice to see you - Que gusto de verte (informal)

I’m glad to see you - Que gusto de verlo (formal)

Comment: This answer maybe somewhat incomplete or incorrect. You should specify which Spanish-speaking country or region these sentences are used in, as in Spain (as the question asks) you don't usually say "qué gusto de verte".